# How to stop users entering a period (.) at the start of an EditText? Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I'm having an issue where I have a number of EditText's with the inputType as 'numberDecimal'. When running the project the user can enter just a period (.) at the start of the EditText which then kills the project when it calculates at the end. Does anyone know a way round this? If it helps I do have if statements set up to catch blank text boxes. Thanks

Comment: Add a `TextChangedListener`. API [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Comment: Rather than (or in addition to) stop the user, I'd focus my efforts on not "killing the project when it calculates" with that input.

Comment: To add to what Thilo has said above, it would be much easier to pass the input to a string and work with that.

Comment: Are you also going to fix it for pressing a 'comma'? For example in the Netherlands, the decimal seperator is a comma and not a dot. I think you should take the advice from @Thilo

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, I'm quite new to android. The answer @nafas gave worked great, Also I didn't realise Netherlands used a comma so I will add that too. As to the issue why this is doing this in the first palce I will look into that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have something like this:

```
    if (textedit.getText().toString().startsWith(".")){
//Do something about it
}
```